# How to supress alert "There is no application set to open URL *custom_protocol*://..." on Safari 7.0

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

There are no any problems with Safari 6.1, Firefox and Chrome.
To supress alerts(application not yet installed) I'm using something like this

```
window.alert = function(title, message) {
  //disable all alerts!
}
```

And this

```
  var prepareLauncherBase = function (){
    var browserName = getBrowserTypeObj()[0].toUpperCase();
    log(browserName);
    // alert(browserName); 
    var aLauncher = document.getElementById('recorder_launcher');
    var iiFrame = document.getElementById('protocol_frame');
    if ( aLauncher == null || aLauncher == 'undefined'){ 
      aLauncher = document.createElement('a');
      aLauncher.setAttribute("id", 'recorder_launcher');
      document.body.appendChild(aLauncher);
     }
    if (browserName == 'MSIE' || browserName == 'FIREFOX' || browserName == 'SAFARI'){ 
      if (iiFrame == null || iiFrame == 'undefined' ) { 
        //alert('creating iframe');
        $('<iframe name="protocol_frame">').appendTo('body'); 
        //iiFrame = document.getElementById('protocol_frame');    
        aLauncher.setAttribute('target', 'protocol_frame');               
    }
    } else {
      aLauncher.setAttribute('target', '_top');
    }
  };
```

Any ideas?

[image: sample of error]